# Системная тема на сайтах открытых через Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

При открытии некоторых сайтов (например stackoverflow.com, github.com) - можно установить системную тему (светлая, темная).

Но это не работает, в системе стоит темная тема - а браузер и все сайты открываются на светлой теме. Linux.

Вопрос: Как заставить всю эту машину работать?

Answer (score 3):

забить адрес

chrome://flags

потом

Auto Dark Mode for Web Contents - ставим - Enabled

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1):

**Что бы Chrome наследовал тему от системы** (*у меня работает с Gnome*) - нужно установить тему GTK+ в настройках браузера.

[image: скриншот настроек темы в chrome]

**Единственное но:** Это всеровно не влияет на работу сайтов, они продолжают грузится в светлой теме.